# Reorganize files in source of a 2gp package

Tags: salesforcedx, 2gp

We have an existing salesforce 2GP package that follow the default directory layout with components in main/default. I would like to break that up into feature folders, but I am not able to move files for existing components and push that. When I move a file, sfdx source tracking sees that as two operations: a delete and an add operation, so it complains that it "Cannot delete managed object". Files for objects that have not yet been published can be moved around freely.

Is there some way to rearrange the file layout of the files in a previously published package?

Please excuse me, if my terminology is inaccurate: I am new in Salesforce land and have inherited this package developed by others.

Thanks, Morten

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to clear your tracking files, which will be fixed by the SFDX CLI the next time you perform a push or deploy.

```
sfdx force:source:tracking:clear
```

In this manner, nothing will be considered a deletion, because all tracking is deleted.

Comment: Seems to work despite the big warning the command issues. Everything ended up as a conflict afterwards but with --forceoverwrite I could push. Seems to solve the issue, thanks!